# Text change on selection of dropdown not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have written a script where I need to change the label name based on selection from `dropdown`.

But problem is that the label is not showing up on selection of `dropdown`, I need some help.

Pardon me if I went wrong somewhere..Thank you.!

**label.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="json-one" class="form-control lable">  
        <option selected="" value="base">Please Select</option>  
        <option value="Doctor">Doctor</option>  
        <option value="Lawyer">Lawyer</option>  
    </select>  
</div>
<div class="form-group"><label id="labelChange"></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" name="lname" minlength="2">
</div>

//.js script

<script>
    var newLabel = '';
$('.lable').on('change', function(){
    $('#labelChange').text(newLabel); //Change the text before changing the value
    switch(this.value){
        case 'Doctor':
            newLabel = 'Clinic name';
            break;
        case 'Lawyer':
            newLabel = 'Practice address';
            break;

    }
}).trigger('change');
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> your problem is `newLabel` variable.
>
> add `$('#labelChange').text(newLabel);` after switch case.

```js
    var newLabel = '';
$('.lable').on('change', function(){
    switch(this.value){
        case 'Doctor':
            newLabel = 'Clinic name';
            break;
        case 'Lawyer':
            newLabel = 'Practice address';
            break;

    }
   $('#labelChange').text(newLabel); //Change the text before changing the value
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="json-one" class="form-control lable">  
        <option selected="" value="base">Please Select</option>  
        <option value="Doctor">Doctor</option>  
        <option value="Lawyer">Lawyer</option>  
    </select>  
</div>
<div class="form-group"><label id="labelChange"></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" name="lname" minlength="2">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton sir..!

Comment: @hari glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and let me know

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#json-one").change(function () {

        var newLabel = '';

        switch (this.value) {
            case 'Doctor':
                newLabel = 'Clinic name';
                break;
            case 'Lawyer':
                newLabel = 'Practice address';
                break;    
        }

        $("#labelChange").html(newLabel);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.!